# MVC4 Razor URL resolution do not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, razor-2

I have upgraded my project from VS2010 MVC3 to VS2012 MVC4 recently and found out that new `Razor URL resolution` feature do not work do not work.

For example I have fav icon

and ~/ path is not automatically resolved by Razor. If I use old style(MVC3) Url.Content resolver everything works fine.

If I create new MVC4 project then paths are resolved successfully. I think that something is left not enabled when VS2012 upgraded my project but can't find what. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have found teh problem by myself. It seems the project was upgraded that it still use MVC3, the project MVC version was not changed automatically.